# Recursive and factory problems

Tags: python, list, recursion

How can you change my code to return a LLL after changes?

I have a list:

```
LLL = [12,[3,[5],[6,[[7, [],8], []]]], [8, [0,87,23,434,444,33]]]
```

and I call this function:

```
def testQ1():
dolist_deep_add1 = factory_dolist_deep_A( (lambda x: x + 1) )
print ('dolist_deep_add1(LLL) : ', dolist_deep_add1(LLL))
```

This function should return the list after changes.
The result Im wating for:

```
LLL = [13,[4,[6],[7,[[8, [],9], []]]], [9, [1,88,24,435,445,34]]]
```

factory_dolist_deep_A code:

```
def factory_dolist_wide_A( fa ):
 def print_wide (L):

    def pw1(x):
        if type(x) is int:
         x = fa(x)
        print(str(x)+' ', end='')

    def pwstart (L, lvl):
        print('\nlevel ' + str(lvl) + " : " , end='')
        pw      (L, lvl)

    def pw (L, lvl):
        if not L: return
        Q = []
        for a in L:
            if type(a) is list:
                if a == [] : pw1('[]')
                else: Q.extend(a)
            else:
                pw1(a)
        pwstart( Q , lvl + 1)

    return pwstart(L, 0)
return print_wide
```

For now it just gets the numbers and print them, without changing the list itself.

I want to change `factory_dolist_wide_A( fa )`: so that it will return a changed List.

It should work the same way as this print function does and not just print the changes, but also make the changes in the list itself.

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  what do you mean by "return a L after changes"?

Comment: i mean that here it just prints, and i want to return the changes list, not just print the changes...

Comment: It's quite clear what he wants. The functions currently print a list changed using a function that's passed in. He wants these functions to return the changed list too.

Comment: How can i do it, Any ideas?...please help..tried everthing

Answer (score 0):

Your code had a lot of unnecessary function definitions. `print_wide(L)` was defined as `pwstart(L, 0)`, and `pwstart(L, lvl)` was defined as `pw(L,lvl)`.

I collapsed all those definitions into `print_wide`. I also changed `pw1()` to `modify()`.

In addition, your existing code had a serious error. Since `Q.extend(a)` made absolutely no sense whatsoever, I removed it.

The following code therefore walks the entire array, and **produces the result you asked for**, but it doesn't print what your original code would have printed.

```
def factory_dolist_wide_A( fa ):
    def print_wide (L, lvl=0):
        def modify(x):
            if type(x) is int:
                x = fa(x)
                print(str(x) + ' ', end='')
            else:
                print('[] ', end='')
            return x

        print('\nlevel ' + str(lvl) + " : " , end='')

        newList = []
        for a in L:
            if type(a) is list:
                newList.append(print_wide(a, lvl+1))
            else:
                newList.append(modify(a))
        return newList
    return print_wide

LLL = [12,[3,[5],[6,[[7, [],8], []]]], [8, [0,87,23,434,444,33]]]

def testQ1():
    dolist_deep_add1 = factory_dolist_wide_A( (lambda x: x + 1) )
    x = dolist_deep_add1(LLL)
    print()
    print('dolist_deep_add1(LLL) : ', x)

testQ1()
```

Comment: thanks for your intersting answer!, helped me alot, but still i was asked not to make a new list but to change the list that was given.

Comment: How would you do it with a simple array like `a = [1,2,3]` ?

Comment: If you cannot understand how to change a list like `a = [1,2,3]` in place, then you first need to learn the basics of Python. You can read the basic Python3 tutorial, and **try the examples** until you understand them. You can also search for examples of people changing python lists in place.